# How can I read the response to a Modbus read request?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, modbus-tk

For a project that uses the Raspberry Pi 4, with a [special shield](https://raspberrypi.dk/en/product/rs485-can-hat-for-raspberry-pi/) as Modbus master I've succesfully written to a register, but I'm having trouble reading from a register. I'm using the Simply Modbus Slave program to test and can see that the request seems to go over well, but I haven't been able to print any data on my Raspberry Pi.

Currently I'm suspecting that the command I use from modbus-tk **(cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS)** send the Read Input Registers command, but doesn't actually receive the response.

I'm therefore seeking help to capture these values, or alternatively save everything received from the slave and find the values among this data.

Also, it could be nice to perhaps print everything sent and received so I can see what's happening in the communication.

This is the current code that I'm using:

```
## To install dependencies:
## sudo pip3 install modbus-tk
##################################################################################################
import serial
import fcntl
import os
import struct
import termios
import array
import time
#import modbus lib
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
import modbus_tk.modbus as modbus
#import modbus_tk.modbus_rtu as modbus_rtu
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

# RS485 ioctls define
TIOCGRS485 = 0x542E
TIOCSRS485 = 0x542F
SER_RS485_ENABLED = 0b00000001
SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND = 0b00000010
SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND = 0b00000100
SER_RS485_RX_DURING_TX = 0b00010000
# rs 485 port
ser1 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC0",19200)
#ser1 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC0",9600)
ser2 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC1",9600)

def rs485_enable():
    buf = array.array('i', [0] * 8) # flags, delaytx, delayrx, padding
    #enable 485 chanel 1
    fcntl.ioctl(ser1, TIOCGRS485, buf)
    buf[0] |=  SER_RS485_ENABLED|SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND
    buf[1]  = 0
    buf[2]  = 0
    fcntl.ioctl(ser1, TIOCSRS485, buf)

    #enable 485 chanel 2
    fcntl.ioctl(ser2, TIOCGRS485, buf)
    buf[0] |=  SER_RS485_ENABLED|SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND
    buf[1]  = 0
    buf[2]  = 0
    fcntl.ioctl(ser2, TIOCSRS485, buf)
#end of rs485_enable():


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = modbus_tk.utils.create_logger("console")

    rs485_enable()

    #set modbus master
    master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(
           serial.Serial(port= '/dev/ttySC0',
           baudrate=9600,
           bytesize=8,
           parity='N',
           stopbits=1,
           xonxoff=0)
       )

    master.set_timeout(5.0)
    master.set_verbose(True)
    logger.info("connected")

    read = logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS, 4, 1))
    print(read)
```

My code is an edited version of my shield's demo code (rtumaster.py) found [here](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DTxr8-EQpdSrBxi0irsB#file=%2FSoftware%2FTest%20Codes%2FMODBUS%2Frtumaster.py::size=3219) *(Software/Test Codes/MODBUS)*.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are able to successfully write to a register then the issue is probably not with your HAT etc (in order for the write to be successful the RS485 link must be operational). Are you seeing the read command in the Simply Modbus log along with it's response but just not getting the response on the Pi?

Comment: Your code should work as intended. Maybe there is something wrong with the slave you are trying to reach. Can you say what kind of slave is it?